# SFTP process output redirection doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, .net-core

I cannot get proper sftp process output. Few commands are work ("exit" and "lls") but other commands output nothing. Host process just keep waiting ReadLine(). In powershell sftp work good. Im using [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "sftp",
    Arguments = $"-P {port} {user}@{server}",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
};
var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

var writer = process.StandardInput;
var reader = process.StandardOutput;

writer.WriteLine("ls");    //Silence
//writer.WriteLine("lls"); //Produce proper output
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a good free library that knows how to do SFTP, like Martin Prikryl's WinSCP lib? Launching console apps and "typing" into them from C# should be an absolute last resort

Comment: @CaiusJard, It has to be easy, if not that "sftp console special behavior". Im not sure now lol